# Google Sheets IMPORTHTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have completed the following script. I want to get a table in my Google Sheet with IMPORTHTML, everything works fine, only if the data changes, then that doesn't change in the Google table. I run the whole thing with a trigger so that will be updated every minute.
But here comes the problem, if I let the whole thing run like this and the data changes on the website, and here comes now the problem that doesn't change in the Google Sheet, the old values ​​are simply taken over and over again and not the new ones. If I delete IMPORTHTML from the cell manually and then copy it back in, it works strangely. But unfortunately it doesn't work with the script and the trigger, what am I doing wrong?

```
function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lager123");
    
  var importXpath_1 = '=IMPORTHTML("URLwithSIMPLEtable","table", 1)';
  
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(importXpath_1);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the content of the cell and then `flush()` it before you set the value:

```
function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lager123");
    
  var importXpath_1 = '=IMPORTHTML("URLwithSIMPLEtable","table", 1)';
  sheet.getRange("A1").clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(importXpath_1);
  
}
```

References:

- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)
- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: This is what I tried alread, but this is also not working. It still takes the old values.

Comment: maybe the data does not get updated every minute, so you need to wait a little bit longer to see the changes?

Comment: @mKeey for the shake of completeness I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For not getting cached response in importhtml, we can append some random query parameter in URL string.

```
var queryString = Math.random(); // This will generate random value
  sheetName.getRange('P7').setValue(queryString); // This random value will be placed in Cell P7

  var cellFunction = '=ImportHtml("URL?"&P7;"table";1)}'; // Value from P7 cell will be appended in URL to avoid caching issue
    sheetName.getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction);
```

I tried this in my project and it's working perfectly.